# Does Removing a WIC from a Cisco router ever effect the Saved Configuration?

Tags: networking, cisco, ios

If I:

1. Shutdown a Cisco Router
2. Remove a WIC and put in a new one of a different type.
3. Boot the router and configure the new WIC just to test it, and don't 'copy run start'
4. Shutdown the router and put the old WIC back
5. Start it up again

Will everything be exactly as I left it before the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have an issue unless there is something wrong with your flash memory. I've done this plenty of times and the only time was an older router that had been running for a while couldn't read from flash on boot. Luckily by that point it was just sitting in our test lab and not production anymore.

I would add a step 0 copy run `tftp://<tftpserver>/<date><router>.cfg` just to be save especially if the router has not been shut down in a long time.

Comment: If I'd been able to give an extra +1 for "also copy the config off to somewhere else", I would've, as is I could only give one +1 for the general answer.